# Gitlab Runner: cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am having the following error message when i try to build a docker image:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://127.0.0.1:2375. Is the
>   docker daemon running?

My gitlab-ci file is the follow:

```
image: docker:19

stages:
    - build

variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://127.0.0.1:2375
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY

first-job:
    stage: build
    script:
        - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/web:latest" .
```

My runner config is the follow:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "sample_runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXX"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:19"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

The docker login command works fine but, fails on build. ¿Any ideas?

Comment: You shouldn’t normally need that `DOCKER_HOST` setting.  (On an installation where that works, any local process or user could trivially get unrestricted root access.)

Comment: Thanks but, if remove that variable then the login fails.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running. On GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105333/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-at-tcp-localhost2375-is-the-docker-daem)