# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running. On GitLab

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to build the CI pipeline in GitLab. I'd like to ask about making the docker work in GitLab CI.

From this issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4501#note_195033385

I'm follow the instruction for both ways. With TLS and not used TLS.
But It's still stuck. Which in same error

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375/. Is the docker daemon running
```

I've try to troubleshooting this problem. follow by below,

1. enable TLS

Which used `.gitlab-ci.yml` and config.toml for enable TLS in Runner.

This my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: docker:19.03
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  IMAGE_NAME: image_name

services:
  - docker:19.03-dind

stages:
  - build

publish:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t$IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-10) .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-10)
  only:
    - master
```

And this my `config.toml`:

```ini
[[runners]]
  name = MY_RUNNER
  url = MY_HOST
  token = MY_TOKEN_RUNNER
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:stable"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]                      
    shm_size = 0
```

2. Disable TLS

`.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
image: docker:18.09
variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2375/
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  IMAGE_NAME: image_name

services:
  - docker:18.09-dind

stages:
  - build

publish:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t$IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-10) .
    - docker push $IMAGE_NAME:$(echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA | cut -c1-10)
  only:
    - master
```

And this my `config.toml`:

```ini
[[runners]]
  environment = ["DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR="]
```

Anyone have idea?

> **Solution**
>
> You can see at the accepted answer.     Moreover, In my case and
> another one. Looks like the root cause it from the Linux server that
> GitLab hosted doesn't has permission to connect Docker. Let's check
> the permission connectivity between GitLab and Docker on your server.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You want to set `DOCKER_HOST` to `tcp://docker:2375`. It's a "service", i.e. running in a separate container, by default named after the image name, rather than localhost.

Here's a `.gitlab-ci.yml` snippet that should work:

```yaml
# Build and push the Docker image off of merges to master; based off
# of Gitlab CI support in https://pythonspeed.com/products/pythoncontainer/
docker-build:
  stage: build

  image:
    # An alpine-based image with the `docker` CLI installed.
    name: docker:stable

  # This will run a Docker daemon in a container (Docker-In-Docker), which will
  # be available at thedockerhost:2375. If you make e.g. port 5000 public in Docker
  # (`docker run -p 5000:5000 yourimage`) it will be exposed at thedockerhost:5000.
  services:
   - name: docker:dind
     alias: thedockerhost

  variables:
    # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon; see
    # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375/
    # Use the overlayfs driver for improved performance:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  script:
    # Download bash:
    - apk add --no-cache bash python3
    # GitLab has a built-in Docker image registry, whose parameters are set automatically.
    # See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-the-gitlab-contai
    #
    # CHANGEME: You can use some other Docker registry though by changing the
    # login and image name.
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"

  # Only build off of master branch:
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: It's still dosen't work ```error during connect: Get http://docker:2375/v1.39/containers/json?all=1: dial tcp: lookup docker on xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:53: no such host``` Which running CI and disable TLS.

Comment: Oh, I found the actual problem. It's not about docker. Just my server didn't allow permission for GitLab runner and docker. I used GitLab with self Hosted. So now it's worked!!.

Comment: The permission is the real key. I have other similar problems solved by running it with sudo. You should make that the accepted answer.

Comment: i have same issue, after changing according to above code

Comment: @zzob Can you describe, which permission you set or wich process you run with sudo?

Comment: In my case I just leaved variable: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" is empty.

Answer (score 8):

You can try to disable tls

```
services:
- name: docker:dind
  entrypoint: ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh", "--tls=false"]
script:
- export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 && docker build --pull -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE} .
```

As there is an interesting reading https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27300

> docker:dind v20 sleeps for 16 seconds if you don't have TLS explicitly disabled, and that causes race condition where build container starts earlier than dockerd container

Comment: you could use args:[--tls=false] without the need to entrypoint

Comment: `args` is not valid in gitlab ci, you can only use `entrypoint` or `command`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. It worked for me when I specified the DOCKER_HOST

```
docker-build:
  stage: build

  image:
    # An alpine-based image with the `docker` CLI installed.
    name: docker:stable

  services:
   - name: docker:dind
     alias: thedockerhost

  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375/
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""

  script:
    # Download bash:
    - apk add --no-cache bash python3
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" "$CI_REGISTRY"
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"

  only:
    - master
```

Comment: You just copied the accepted answer? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

For me the accepted answer didn't work. Instead I configured the TLS certificate volume for the runner

```
[[runners]]
...
  [runners.docker]
    ...
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
```

and I added a variable for the certificate directory in my .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
```

according to this article:
https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/#configure-tls

and this one:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#docker-in-docker-with-tls-enabled-in-the-docker-executor

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the DOCKER_HOST from the .gitlab-ci file. That trick will do magic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use docker and privileged mode:

```
sudo gitlab-runner register -n \
  --url "https://gitlab.com/" \
  --registration-token REGISTRATION_TOKEN \
  --executor docker \
  --description "My Docker Runner" \
  --docker-image "docker:24.0.5" \
  --docker-privileged \
  --docker-volumes "/certs/client"
```

- This command registers a new runner to use the docker:24.0.5 image
  (if none is specified at the job level). To start the build and
  service containers, it uses the privileged mode. If you want to use
  Docker-in-Docker, you must always use privileged = true in your
  Docker containers.
- This command mounts /certs/client for the service    and build
  container, which is needed for the Docker client to use the
  certificates in that directory.

The previous command creates a config.toml entry similar to the following example:

```
[[runners]]
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = TOKEN
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:24.0.5"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

You can now use docker in the job script. You should include the docker:24.0.5-dind service:

```
default:
  image: docker:24.0.5
  services:
    - docker:24.0.5-dind
  before_script:
    - docker info

variables:
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t my-docker-image .
    - docker run my-docker-image /script/to/run/tests
```