# GitLab CI: docker container cannot connect to MongoDB service

Tags: mongodb, docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

In a GitLab CI pipeline I need to connect my own C++ code from a docker container to a MongoDB running as servive but I cannot connect.

This is a minimal gitlab-ci.yml example showing the problem:

```
stages:
  - connect1
  - connect2

image: docker:latest

variables:
  MONGOIMAGE: "mongo:4.2.3-bionic"
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "root"
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "geheim"

connect1:
  stage: connect1
  services:
    - name: $MONGOIMAGE
  image: mongo
  script:
    - mongo --host mongo --username $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME --password $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "db.help()"

connect2:
  stage: connect2
  services:
    - name: $MONGOIMAGE
  script:
    - docker run --rm mongo mongo --host mongo --username $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME --password $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "db.help()"
```

The error message of connect2 is that the host cannot be found:

```
connecting to: mongodb://mongo:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-06-04T16:20:47.614+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server mongo:27017, connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for mongo:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative) :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
@(connect):2:6
2020-06-04T16:20:47.615+0000 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2020-06-04T16:20:47.615+0000 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I already tried with `--host localhost` but this is working neighter. How can I achive that a container started with `docker run` like in connect2 can connect to the MongoDB service?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution:

```
connect2:
  stage: connect2
  services:
    - name: $MONGOIMAGE
  script:
    - ping mongo -c 5
    - docker run --rm mongo mongo --add-host mongo:`cat /etc/hosts | grep mongo | awk '{print $1}'` --net host --username $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME --password $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD --eval "db.help()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker is client/server application. You're running the client, but there is no server. So you need to run a Docker daemon using Docker-in-Docker.

You can see an example GitLab CI config here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61106578/6214034

And the relevant documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html

Comment: I think the server is specified by the 'service' keyword. And as far as I understand my pipeline uses already docker-in-docker. With stage 'connect1' I proved that the server is running, I can connect and get the expected help summary. Only stage 2 cannot connect but should have the same server running like in stage 1.